# Can't Connect to MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, connection-string

I'm trying to conntect to a mysql database for the first time. Can you see what's not working correctly below?
I get an error on line 3. 
What would my server address look like from Godaddy to my database? I found that address in my control panel.

Thanks for any help. Never programmed using PHP before.

```
<body>
<?php
 $con = mysql_connect("MydbName.db.3924516.hostedresource.com ","Userid","password");
 if (!$con)
 {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Gallerys");

echo "<table border='1'>
 <tr>
 <th>Thumb Url </th>
 <th>Gallery Url</th>
 </tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['THUMBURL'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['GALLERYURL'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?> 

</body>
```

Comment: I hate to burst your bubble since you've just learned `mysql_*` but that extension is in the pre-deprecation phase and at the very least you need to find a tutorial that uses the `mysqli` extension or `PDO`. And make sure it mentions "prepared statements." Because if the tutorial doesn't, it's total garbage.

Comment: whats the error message you're getting?

Comment: Thanks Ill look for that tutorial.

Comment: Are you using the correct "UserID" and "Password" rather than just string literals? i.e. maybe you should set $userID and $password to whatever your control panel / mysqladmin says it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try check back the authenication settings, you might use the wrong host, username or password.

```
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("usually it is localhost","your MYSQL username","your MYSQL password"); 

// Checking the login details. 
// Example of default xampp login details: $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  
// Xampp MYSQL default does not have password. 

    if (!$con) // If the login details are wrong, it will should an error.
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the exact error it is hard to be sure but on line 3 you have an extra space after hostedresource.com.  Try removing the space between the end of the hostname and the quatation mark.  Like so:

```
$con = mysql_connect("MydbName.db.3924516.hostedresource.com","Userid","password");
```